# Change a cell's background color based on text content of multiple other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I want that, if an Excel cell A1 contains text/name that is already inputted into cells F1 through F20, the cell A1 background color should change. Example:

If I enter `John Smith` in cell A1 and the name `John Smith` is contained in cell F1, I need cell A1 automatically to change to bright red background color. This also needs to work if the name is entered in, say, cell F5.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you done so far to solve the issue and why did that not work?

Comment: One solution would be use a `COUNTIF` formula within `Conditional Formatting`. see [Use a formula to apply conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) for more complete information.

Answer (score 0):

Please select A1, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH(A1,F$1:F$20,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, OK, OK.